# How to update progress dialog using counter from the task being run in Eclipse jobs API

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, progressdialog

I'm using Eclipse jobs API for the first time. I have a plugin that needs to call a method from a jar file to process large data, so I need to show a progress dialog. My question is, how can I update the progress dialog with the number of data items that had been processed? right now I have this code

```
Job job = new Job("Annotate"){
                    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor){
                        monitor.beginTask("Annotation..", annotate.getTotal());
                        annotate.annotateData();
                        monitor.done();

                            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        SaveUtils.saveEntry(wizard.getEntry(), AnnotationEntry);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        return Status.OK_STATUS;
                    }

                };
                job.setUser(true);
                job.schedule();
```

annotate object has a method that return the number of the data items that had been processed, but I don't know how let the progress dialog talk to the annotate object. Please help with thoughts or examples.

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the progress while `annotate.annotateData()` is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this tricky problem. Here are the steps:

1. I created an interface inside my annotation package called IControlProgressDialog with a method void setCurrentIndex();
2. in the method annotateData I added a parameter of type IControlProgressDialog.
3. inside the loop that iterates over my data items I called the setCurrentIndex();
4. I created a class inside my plugin called ImplControlProgressDialog that implements that interface and it defines an object reference of type IProgressMonitor.
5. in the ImplControlProgressDialog I implemented the method setCurrentIndex() as

   void setCurrentIndex(){
   monitor.worked(1);
   }

This gave me the ability to update the progress dialog while the annotate.annotateData() is running on another thread.

The updated code of my job:

```
Job job = new Job("Annotate"){
                protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor){
                    monitor.beginTask("Annotation..", annotate.getTotal());
                    ImplControlProgressDialog control = new ImplControlProgressDialog (monitor);
                    annotate.annotateData(control);
                    monitor.done();

                        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    SaveUtils.saveEntry(wizard.getEntry(), AnnotationEntry);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    return Status.OK_STATUS;
                }

            };
            job.setUser(true);
            job.schedule();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would call monitor.worked() enough times with a sum of parameters to match the amount of work you said would be needed with annotate.getTotal(). Note that if you're doing your work on the UI thread as shown, you won't see updates all that smoothly--they require the UI thread, too.

Comment: I'm doing my work inside job object to create a new thread, so I'm no using the UI thread. your point of using mintor.worked() doesn't solve the problem because the problem is how to sync the progress dialog with the annotate.annotation().

Comment: Display.getDefault().asyncExec() runs that Runnable on the UI thread. I see no call to annotate.annotation().

Answer (score 0):

If your long running method does not provide a way to find out about progress then the best you could do would be to run the method in a separate thread and have the `Job` update the progress monitor periodically and stop when the thread terminates.